Convert mxf and dnxhd to smaller format
I have various HDDs worth of MXF and DNXHD that are huge files done for networks.
I'm in the need of making a personal showreel from some frames of each video, but have no storage to store 10 TB of data just for 500MB of real usable data.
Can I convert them to mp4 h264 or h265 full hd short gop or intra I for editing ?
What ffmpeg options you suggest to use?
Was trying with adobe media encoder but the only option that cames to my mind is the keyframe distance, should I set it to 1 or 4 or 8 as alternative to ffmpeg?
